# fetch is not defined error in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use fetch in my project but there is an error saying

> fetch is not defined

[image]

Someone knowing why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this a code style error? if so, you can disable that line according to your code styling library

If not, what you need to import to make it work is:

```
import "isomorphic-fetch";
```

Comment: Actually, the response.data should be response.json() after that it turn out to be code style error. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 7):

It might be better to add it in your .eslintrc config instead since the Fetch API is already included in React Native.

Details:
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4015#issuecomment-301920490

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are using new JS version ES6 then you can fetch your url request like this:

```
var params = {key:'value'}

var reqOpts = {}
reqOpts.method = 'POST'
reqOpts.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
reqOpts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
reqOpts.body = JSON.stringify(params)

var url = 'YOUR_URL'

let response = await fetch(url, reqOpts)

return response.json()
      .then((jsonData) => {
        return jsonData
      })
```